# EmbeddedViewRef children are empty

Tags: angular, directive

I am writing a structural directive and am facing issues:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appClipboard]',
})
export class ClipboardDirective implements OnInit{
    @Input() set appClipboard(tag: string) {
    }

    constructor(
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private containerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        const view = this.containerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        console.log(view.rootNodes[0].childNodes);
        console.log(view.rootNodes[0].childNodes.length);
        console.log(view.rootNodes[0].firstChild);
    }
}
```

The output of the console is as follows:
[image]

How is that possible?
Why are there elements when printing the array directly, but as soon as I touch it
in code, its empty?

Kind regards
Samuel

Comment: Can you provide a complete repro of your issue on stackblitz ? I can't reproduce it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kcopwz?file=src%2Fmain.ts